# Infinite Loop Error in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, infinite-loop

I have this short code here. But it is not printing in wing ide 4.1 using python because it is an infinite loop. Any ideas of what I could add or how to fix it so it prints?

```
import random
coins = 1000
wager = 2000
while ((coins>0) and (wager!= 0)):
x = random.randint(0,10)
y = random.randint(0,10)
z = random.randint(0,10)
print x,
print y,
print z
```

Comment: Indentation is important in Python; can you please indent the lines after `while` correctly to reflect your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted won't do anything but pick 3 psuedo-random numbers until the end of time. You have to add some win/loss conditions. As of now the x, y and z are just numbers. If you want to make a gambling game you have to add some victory conditions like:

```
if x + y + z > 10
```

just an example but your program needs to be able to tell if the player won. then it needs to make changes to the players total amount of money and ask for a new wager. You also might want to add logic to make sure the player can't bet more than they have.

```
import random
coins = 1000
wager = 0
while True: #main loop
    print('you have {} coins'.format(coins))
    if coins == 0: #stops the game if the player is out of money
        print('You are out of money! Scram, deadbeat!')
        break
    while wager > coins or wager == 0: #loops until player enters a non-zero wager that is less then the total amount of coins
        wager = int(input('Please enter your bet (enter -1 to exit): '))
    if wager < 0: # exits the game if the player enters a negative
        break
    print('All bets are in!') 
    x = random.randint(0,10)
    y = random.randint(0,10)
    z = random.randint(0,10)
    print(x,y,z) #displays all the random ints
    if x + y +z > 10: #victory condition, adds coins for win
        print('You win! You won {} coins.'.format(wager))
        coins += wager
    else: #loss and deduct coins
        print('You lost! You lose {} coins'.format(wager))
        coins -= wager
    wager = 0 # sets wager back to 0 so our while loop for the wager validation will work
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code never alters `coins` *or* `wager`, so the `while` condition is *always* True:

```
while ((coins>0) and (wager!= 0)):
    # code that doesn't touch coins or wager
```

Perhaps you meant to also subtract one of `x`, `y` or `z` from `coins` or `wager`?

As to why the code doesn't print in Wing IDE; this depends entirely on your indentation. If the `print` statements are not part of the loop, they are never reached and never executed. Try creating a loop that does not run infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no modification to your breaking condition in your while loop.

In your case, the breaking condition is when `wager is not 0` and `coins > 0`, so **you have to modify either the `coins` or `wager` variable in your code**, e.g.

```
import random
coins = 1000; wager = 2000
while coins > 0 and wager is not 0:
  x,y,z = [random.randint(0,10)]*3
  print x,y,z
  wager-= 1000
  coins-= 100
```

As @martijn Indentation is important in python, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Indentation:

```
for _ in range(10):
  x = 'hello world'
  print x
```

[out]:

```
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
```

When the `print x` is not indented:

```
for _ in range(10):
  x = 'hello world'
print x
```

[out]:

```
hello world
```